# Reset password using google openIDConnect

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, openid-connect

I am working on a project where we integrating the google openIdConnect to let user sign-in to the application using google auth. I taken help from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect to authenticate user.

I also need to allow user to reset the password within the application post user logged in. But not able to found any specific help on this.

Can we able to reset password using openIDConnect or it not possible at all. If its possible then how.

NOTE: My preference would be client side solution then a server side.

Answer (score 0):

One of great side effects of OpenID Connect is that you do not need to care about user registration+confirmation and password reset processes within your application. If you are using google as an identity provider, google takes care of this.

At most, you could link to password-reset URL from google, but:

1. It is already linked on the google's login page.
2. Google could change URL without prio notice as it is not a part of OpenID Connect specification.
3. Why do you think [google will be using passwords for authentication](http://techcrunch.com/2015/12/22/google-begins-testing-password-free-logins/)?